# Trying to copy static cell value from workbook A and paste into dynamic location in workbook B

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to:

- Copy cell `"B2:C2"` from every workbook in a folder from the `"Results"` worksheet.
- Paste the value into Cell `A1:A2` `Sheet1` in workbook `"x"`in the same folder.

I think I know how to open and `do something` to every workbook within a folder.

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim WorkbookCounter As Long
WorkbookCounter = 1
Dim Filepath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim RowCounter As Long
RowCounter = 1

Filepath = "C:\Test\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

'Opens workbooks located C:\Test\ in order
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        'Copy cells B2 & C2 from the results worksheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("x").Range(Cells(RowCounter, 1), Cells(RowCounter, 2)).Value = _
         wb.Worksheets("Results").Range("B2:C2").Value

        'Close wb most recently opened
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1

    If WorkbookCounter > 1000 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MyFile = Dir

    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1

Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Update: With help in the comments below the above code now correctly loops through the correct folder and updates cell `A1:A2`.

Instead of overwriting cell `A1:A2` I'd like to paste the copied text one line down.

`i.e. Workbook 1 = A1:A2, Workbook 2 = B1:B2, etc`

Comment: If you put `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules, you'll catch errors like this.  `Book1.xlsm` should be a string - it needs to be in quotes - `"Book1.xlsm"`.

Comment: When coping with equals, your ranges must be equal. e.g. A1:B1=B2:C2

Comment: @GMalc thank you for the tips! I'll remember them. I've made the changes you've suggested and I'm getting the same errors. I'll update the OP

Comment: @Comintern you too sorry thought they were both from GMalc!

Comment: Is `Workbooks(Book1.xlsm)` where you have your macro? if it is the just use `ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("x")` or you could declare it as a variable.

Comment: @GMalc Workbooks(Book1.xlsm) is where the macro is yes. ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("x") produces the same error.

Comment: Doesn't this macro just write over the existing value in cells A1:B1 in Book1, sheet=x? For example, if there are a dozen worksheets in a given folder, the value of A1:B1 will just contain the value of the last workbook that you processed.

Comment: `Workbooks("wb").Worksheets("Results")` just needs to be `wb.Worksheets("Results")`

Comment: @GMalc, *your ranges must be equal* ... or just the top-left cell of the destination.

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for the note about "Option Explicit". I always wondered effect that had.

Comment: @Jeeped, I always understood, and correct me if i'm wrong, when using copy/paste you can use the "top-left" cell of the destination. But when using Range = Range it must be the same size.

Comment: @GMalc, Yes, that's correct. In fact, for range=range I always resize the destination with the dimensions of the source with .rows.count and .columns.count.

Comment: @GMalc the first progress in hours! Changing your last suggestion has pasted the data from the first workbook in the folder to the correct cells. Now I'm getting an automation error at a non-specified location.

Comment: @Tedinoz that's a good point.... I've four test workbooks in the folder with workbook 1 having 1 in the cells to copy, workbook 2 having 2 in the cells to copy etc and I was hoping I'd end up with 4 in the cells meaning at least the loop was working

Comment: Tedinoz, i have to go, but i'm sure someone else can provide assistance.

Comment: @Jeeped, I agree i like to use resize, but i always try to keep the information i provide here, as simple as possible due to the experience of OPs.

Comment: @Jeeped probably a good idea, never even heard of resizing!

Comment: @L23P That's OK, we just loop though the workbooks, and use the loop number to drive the row number with a "Cells" command. Just got to test it.

Comment: How about. 1=before the do-while, create a variable "row_counter" as long, set value to 1, 2=the destination for the paste is "Range(Cells(row_counter, 1), Cells(row_counter, 2))", and 3=before the loop command, row_counter = row_counter+1

Comment: @Tedinoz I've declared `RowCounter as Long, RowCounter = 1` I'm getting an application-defined or object defined error with this: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("x").Range(Cells(RowCounter, 1), Cells(RowCounter, 2)).Value = _
         wb.Worksheets("Results").Range("B2:C2").Value`

Comment: @Tedinoz updated OP

Comment: Is the ".value" statement for the source ("the results sheet") necessary? IN fact, are either of the ".value" statements necessary?

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar statement just the other day but used the full VBA Copy-> Destination syntax. The equivalent here would be something like:"wb.Worksheets("Results").Range("B2:C2").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("x").Range(Cells(RowCounter, 1), Cells(RowCounter, 2))". There's a single space between the words 'Copy' and 'Destination'.

Comment: @L23P You mean that it isn't copying down the rows? BTW, did you add the increment to row_counter before the loop ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any check to make sure you are not trying to open ThisWorkbook and there is no check to see if there is a Results worksheet in the source workbook; in fact there is no check to ensure that you are trying to open a workbook at all, you could be trying to open a JPG.

Further error control could be added to ensure that you are not trying to open another workbook that is already open. I suspect that after all the testing, you might have a few.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim myFile As String, filepath As String
    Dim wbc As Long, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

    wbc = 0
    filepath = "C:\Test\"

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'only try to open workbooks
    myFile = Dir(filepath & "*.xls*")

    'Opens workbooks located C:\Test\ in order
    Do While Len(myFile) > 0
        'make sure myFile isn't ThisWorkbook
        If Split(myFile & ".", ".")(0) <> Split(ThisWorkbook.Name & ".", ".")(0) Then

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath & myFile, ReadOnly:=True)

            'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            'check if there is a Results worksheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Results")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                 'transfer cells B2 & C2 from the results worksheet
                 With ws.Range("B2:C2")
                     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("x").Range("A1").Offset(wbc, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
                 End With
            End If

            'Close wb most recently opened
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

            wbc = wbc + 1
            If wbc > 1000 Then Exit Do

        End If

        Set ws = Nothing
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the error checking, that seems sensible. The code you've posted doesn't throw up an error but it isn't printing anything into A1. It look like it's opening all the workbooks in the test folder but isn't pasting anything anywhere from what I can see.

Comment: I actually built a test bench and ran through several workbooks both with Results worksheets and without. I'd suggest you step through it with F8 to see what is being skipped.

Comment: You're a genius! I haven't had my morning coffee, thank you so much. It's working perfectly. The files in question will be .xlms, I assume that won't cause an issue if I change the .xls reference?

Comment: No, but when you use a wildcard match restrict the matches as much as you can. `*.xl*` is probably the widest pattern for workbooks; for only xlm then probably `*.xlm` would be best.